# Error with my server file - Invalid URL: index.js

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am getting the following error when trying to run my server (index.js):

```
Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: index.js
```

The code block is here:

```
app.get('/:url', async function (req, res) {
      
      try {
    
      
        return res.status(200).json(data);
    
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
        return res.status(500).json({ message : "Oops." });
        
      }
```

With the specific line of code it is referring to is:

```
const site = await .open(decodeURIComponent(req.params.url));
```

Has anyone ever encountered this error before, and have any idea how to fix it in this context? Not sure how it is throwing an error for my entire index.js server

Note: This is an express app

Comment: Think you should be using `encodeURIComponent` instead of `decodeURIComponent`

Comment: `index.js` is still not a valid URL. Why did you delete your previous question?

Comment: @nickzoum Nope, doesn't do anything to fix. Thanks, though!

Comment: decodeURIComponent('index.js') is just 'index.js' so that's fine.

Comment: @xehpuk How is index.js being pulled into this however? Not sure where that comes from besides it being the file name

Comment: @KirtMac99 By calling `GET /index.js` on your server.

Comment: @AllanWind Usually when you're creating a url you encode the string and when you're trying to get data from the url you decode, so that was the first thing I saw.

Comment: I think wappalyzer.open() expects a full url.

Comment: @xehpuk the app.get request should be to whatever the url the user searches for (returns results from wappalyzer). How can I counter this error?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, but what if I do not know the URL at the moment? As in it depends on what is searched on the front end?

Comment: @KirtMac99 We don't know your frontend, but this probably happens by searching for `index.js` instead of a real URL.

Comment: https://www.wappalyzer.com/docs/api/v2/basics/ is the documentation, I think, but it's sales page.  Ugh.  I am out.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `req.params.url` is `index.js`.

A web browser can expand `index.js` into an absolute URL because it knows that it can use the URL of the current HTML document as the base URL.

You're running your code in Node.js. It doesn't run inside a document. There is no base URL.

You need to provide an *absolute* URL (e.g. `http://example.com/index.js`) yourself.

That said, I suspect wappalyzer may require that you give it the URL to an HTML document not a JS file.

Comment: Why would my server file need to be shown in the URL? Should it not be hidden from the client?

Comment: @KirtMac99 — There is no reason for you to show your server-side source code to the client, and I didn't suggest that you should. You need to provide an absolute URL (probably of an HTML document) to wappalyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since there isn't much that i can see about your usage, I'm just going to assume you went to something like `http://localhost/index.js`.

The problem now is, that wappalyzer does not actually get a valid url. It gets index.js without any form of protocol (http/https/ws/wss...). This means it doesn't know what to do and tells you that the url you provided is invalid.

In order to fix this go to  `http://localhost/https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Findex.js` or append https:// or something similar to your parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function() {
    obtenerTasasDeCambio();

    document.getElementById('crear').addEventListener('click', crearTasaDeCambio);
};

function obtenerTasasDeCambio() {
        fetch('/tasasDeCambio')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => mostrarTasasDeCambio(data))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

    function mostrarTasasDeCambio(tasasDeCambio) {
        let tabla = document.getElementById('tablaTasasDeCambio');
        tasasDeCambio.forEach(tasa => {
            let fila = tabla.insertRow();
            let celdaMoneda = fila.insertCell();
            let celdaTasa = fila.insertCell();
            let celdaAcciones = fila.insertCell();
            celdaMoneda.textContent = tasa.moneda; 

            let entradaTasa = document.createElement('input');
            entradaTasa.type = 'number';
            entradaTasa.value = tasa.tasa;
            entradaTasa.id = 'tasa-' + tasa._id;
            celdaTasa.appendChild(entradaTasa);

            let botonActualizar = document.createElement('button');
            botonActualizar.textContent = 'Actualizar';
            botonActualizar.addEventListener('click', function() {
                actualizarTasaDeCambio(tasa.id);
            });

            let botonBorrar = document.createElement('button');
            botonBorrar.textContent = 'Borrar';
            botonBorrar.addEventListener('click', function() {
                borrarTasaDeCambio(tasa._id);
            });
            
            celdaAcciones.appendChild(botonActualizar);
            celdaAcciones.appendChild(botonBorrar);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.